# Setting link hover property with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the background color of a link with jQuery,
the orginal CSS for the link is

```
#container ul li:hover ul li a{
    background: #FF0000
}
```

I'm trying the following jQuery code, but it does not seem to work.

```
jQuery('#container ul li:hover ul li a').css('background', '#FF0000');
```

I can set the css for the normal links, but its only causing problem with the link hover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
jQuery('#container ul li ul li a').hover(function(){
   $(this).css('background', '#FF0000');
})
```

or this :

```
jQuery('#container ul li').hover(function(){
   $(this).find("ul li a").css('background', '#FF0000');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with the jquery hover function. http://api.jquery.com/hover/
And re-set the color.